# Have a macro evaluate to different stuff depending on whether it will be hyphenated

Tags: macros, line-breaking, hyphenation

Given a command like this

```
\newcommand{\AB}{$\textsf{A} \subseteq \textsf{B/string}$}
```

is it possible to have the string evaluate to something like

```
\newcommand{\ABhyp}{\textsf{A} is contained in \textsf{B/string}}
```

if TeX determines to hyphenate `\AB` or if there will be an overfull box using `\AB`?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question.  However, you might consider preventing hyphenation in `\AB` by defining it as `{\mbox{$\textsf{A} \subseteq \textsf{B/string}$}}`.  It is a short-enough expression that it will hopefully not break any alignments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by no means ideal, but you could define the breakpoint as a `\discretionary{<pre-break>}{<post-break>}{<no-break>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\AB}{%
  \textsf{A}%
  \discretionary{\mbox{ is}}{\mbox{contained in }}{\mbox{${}\subseteq{}$}}%
  \textsf{B/string}%
}

\begin{document}

\AB

Some text to fill the line width with characters and then we have the \AB.

\end{document}
```

The reason why it's not ideal is that `\mbox` removes any of the inter-word spacing adjustments typical of making lines fit within the horizontal width. So, the spacing between `A` and `is` and `contained`, `in` and `B/string` might be slightly different from surrounding inter-word spaces. However, this depends heavily on the context of the paragraph it's used in, and might not be visible under most conditions. Sentences with long words (having few inter-word spaces) might emphasize this.